# Running elasticsearch jetty plugin

Tags: java, security, elasticsearch, jetty

I had an elasticsearch(1.1.0) server running well on my windows server vm with kibana, head and marvel plugins.
I try to add the jetty plugin, so I:

-downloaded the latest jar(0.90.0) from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sonian/elasticsearch-jetty

-put the jar in the elasticsearch home folder : /elasticsearch-1.1.0/

-open a cmd prompt, I went to elasticsearch home folder and write the following command line

```
D:\elasticsearch-1.1.0>bin\plugin -i jetty -u file:jetty.jar
-> Installing jetty...
Trying file:jetty.jar...
Downloading .DONE
Installed jetty into D:\elasticsearch-1.1.0\plugins\jetty

D:\elasticsearch-1.1.0>
```

Then I add the following line to my elasticsearch.yml (as said at https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty):

```
http.type: com.sonian.elasticsearch.http.jetty.JettyHttpServerTransportModule
```

And now, when I am starting the elasticsearch service, I get this error:

```
Windows could not start the elasticsearch 1.1.0(storage) service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

In elasticsearch logs, this is what I have:

```
2014-05-20 14:17:19,382][INFO ][node                     ] [MYNODE]      version[1.1.0], pid[33652], build[2181e11/2014-03-25T15:59:51Z]
[2014-05-20 14:17:19,382][INFO ][node                     ] [MYNODE]   initializing ...
[2014-05-20 14:17:19,413][INFO ][plugins                  ] [MYNODE]   loaded [marvel, jetty], sites [marvel, cluster, head, kibana]
[2014-05-20 14:17:19,819][ERROR][bootstrap                ] {1.1.0}: Initialization   Failed ...
- NoClassDefFoundError[org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Logger]
ClassNotFoundException[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger]
```

I am having a lot of troubles to add the jetty plugin to secure the access to es. If someone could explain me in a detailled way, it would be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.90 of the Jetty plugin isn't compatible with version 1.1.0 of Elasticsearch. If you go to the github page, https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty, instead you can see the plugin compatibility table and download the correct version.

Comment: Thanks. Being behind my company proxy, I cannot access to the link. Is there any other way I can access to: https://oss-es-plugins.s3.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch-jetty/elasticsearch-jetty-1.1.1-beta.zip. I just want to get the specified jetty zip.

Comment: Not that I know of, if you can't access files from Amazon S3 or Github and you're a developer for a company, I would strongly recommend having a word with that company about their operating practices... ;)